# Reading Response from IDTech Card Reader/Writer C# Com Port

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# project in visual studio 2015. For this project I have to read/write data to a hi-co Magnetic ID card. The model of writer I'm using is the IDTECH IDWA-336133B reader/writer.

The company gives you a set of commands to send to the unit through an emulated rs232 port (physical USB port). So far I have sent commands to turn the LEDs on and off on the unit with `System.IO.Ports`, but I have yet to figure out how I am supposed to receive data from the swipe, or write data on the swipe.

I'm attaching the `frmMain.cs` file I have, and the manual for the unit. You can see the commands on that manual that I'm using (Sending the hex code as bytes).

So what I was wondering: is there a way someone can show me the correct syntax / way to write a command to read the data from the card swipe back in?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace SerialPortCommunication
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static SerialPort _serialPort;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            _serialPort = new SerialPort();
            byte[] command = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x81 };
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM4";


            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            _serialPort.Open();

            _serialPort.Write(command, 0, command.Length);

            _serialPort.Close();
            _serialPort.Dispose();
        }

        private void btnLedon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort();
            byte[] command = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x84};
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM4";


            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            _serialPort.Open();

            _serialPort.Write(command, 0, command.Length);

            _serialPort.Close();
            _serialPort.Dispose();
        }

        private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort();
            byte[] command = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x52 };
            byte[] hico = new byte[] {0x1B, 0x78 };
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM4";
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 10000;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
            byte[] answer = new byte[] { };


            _serialPort.Open();

            // setting it to hico cards just incase
            _serialPort.Write(hico, 0, hico.Length);
            //sends command to read data
            _serialPort.Write(command, 0, command.Length);
            // I don't know if this is even remotely right
            String response =_serialPort.ReadExisting();

            lblReadData.Text = response;
            _serialPort.Close();
            _serialPort.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is sloppy code, but I'm just trying to get it working so I can migrate it to the real program and do it correctly.

Here is part of the [manual](http://www.idtechproducts.com/download/doc_details/137-user-manual-ez-writer-workshop-utility-and-technical-guide.html) that has all the hex codes and responses etc.:

> ### Command & Response Introduction
>
> The EzWriter supports the following commands.  The responses are
>   provided.
>
> Command: Reset Buffer
>  Command code: <ESC> a
>  Hex code: 1B
>   61
>  Response: none
>  Description: This command reset the EzWriter
>   buffer to initial state.  Encoding settings are not affected by this
>   command.
>
> Command: Read
>  Command code: <ESC> r
>  Hex code: 1B 72
>   Response: [data block] <ESC> [status byte]
>  Description: This
>   command requests the EzWriter to read a card swiped and respond with
>   the data read.
>
> Command: Write
>  Command code: <ESC> w [data block]
>  Hex
>   code: 1B 77 [data block]
>  Response: <ESC> [status byte]
>   Description: This command requests the EzWriter to write the data
>   block into the card swiped.
>
> Command: Communication test
>  Command code: <ESC> e
>  Hex
>   code: 1B 65
>  Response: <ESC> y [1B] [79]
>  Description:
>   This command is used to verify that the communication link between
>   computer and the EzWriter is up and good.

Comment: I cleaned this up, but you should really cut the manual excerpt down to what is relevant. Or remove it completely.

Comment: Cleaned up the manual a pretty good bit. Thank you, I should have done that in the first place. Frustration had me blind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serial port class fires the DataReceived event when data is sent to it. Keep in mind that this event fires on its own thread, separate from the main thread running the UI of your form. In order to receive data you need to implement this event. I did a quick example but have not tested it.

```
class Program
{
    private static SerialPort _SerialPort;
    private const int baudRate = 9600;
    private const string PortName = "Com4";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        _SerialPort = new SerialPort(PortName, baudRate);
        _SerialPort.DataReceived += _readSerialPort_DataReceived;
        _SerialPort.Open();
       var command = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x81 };
       Console.WriteLine("Sending {0} to device", command);
       sendData(command);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        _SerialPort.Close();

    }

    static void sendData(byte[] command)
    {
        _SerialPort.Write(command,0,command.Length);
    }

    static void _readSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sp = (SerialPort) sender;
        // Edited following line. See comment
        var data = sp.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received: {0}", data);
        //you may be able to do something like this as well but I am not sure if this is a blocking call
        var messageLength = 10;
        var buffer = new byte[messageLength];
        sp.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);            
        //if you are going to update the UI you need to invoke a delegate method on the main thread
    }
}
```

There are a few options on how to read the data as well if you want to read it into a byte array or only take a snip-it of the data returned.

More info on Serial port class: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)

Info on updating UI elements from another thread: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx)

MSDN example of Serial port DataReceived event: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Wow, I really didn't expect such an awesome answer. I will try this as soon as I can and let you know. For now though, this answers my questions completely. I can't believe I didn't think of some type of event or event-handler that would grab that data.

Comment: Well, I got this working by using the event you mentioned and using a waitHandle to pause the program until the data is actually received. However, sometimes I swipe the card and I'll get the entire string on the card "123456789" and some times I swipe it and only get 1234, or 12, or 123456 so on and so forth. Any idea at all why this may be happening?

Comment: Hey @HunterDishner sorry for the delay. If you havn't figured it out yet it, It is because of the sp.readexisting() I gave you. That appears to only read what is on the buffer and fires to fast to catch the rest of the data being written to it. There are a few other options, i would suggest looking into using the readLine function instead. If that doesn't work you may be able to use the read function and specify the length it should read. None of that is tested though and depends on how you are given the data.

I have updated the answer.